# Excel Get the location of a string in another sheet and return a value from the same line in another sheet

Tags: excel, match

I need a formula for the following situation: I have to sheets:
 Sheet1, Sheet2. In Sheet2,    B30 I used this formula:

```
  MATCH($D30,Sheet1!D:D,0)
```

and it returns 7

Now I want to change this formula to return me the value from Sheet1
 but not on the same column  but B Smt like

```
   Sheet1!$B$7
```

and the expected to be TextToPrint6(see pic1,2 and for expected pic 3)
 I need this to happen only if there is a match, else remain blank

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVwDS.jpg)

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHaoq.jpg)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFebG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH returns the relative location not a result.  It needs to go with INDEX:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH($D30,Sheet1!D:D,0))
```

Comment: Is it any way to add a check before, like if D30 is empty or there is no match then let it  blank else your formula

Comment: I found it : =IF(D30<>"",(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH($D30,Sheet1!D:D,0)),"")),"")        Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The match function returns the relative index of the item in the range you defined. if you need the item itself use lookup or index.